# Vim Replace Some Words Before Paste

Tags: vim, replace, vim-plugin, editing

For example, if I copied the line:

```
BST.left = child.getLeft("left");
```

Before I paste it, I want to change all "left" to "right", in other words, I want to paste the line:

```
BST.right = child.getRight("right");
```

Is there an easy way to do this in Vim commands? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you change it after you paste it? You can select the text and then apply regex to only that statement changing all the `left`s to `Right`s

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why its significant that you make a change in between the copy and paste steps.

But it is easy to make the change after pasting the line.

e.g.
Vyp
/right  viwy
/left 
viwpn.